# Ruling on shaving the head?

Tags: sunni, shaving

I have some hair damage and was recommended to shave my head to regrow new hair again. Is this forbidden? I know it is haram to imitate a man or a Kuffar women but I'm doing neither, I only want to get rid of my damaged hair and regrow it again.

Comment: A similar question was asked on: http://islamqa.info/en/95364 It should provide all the details you need. In their words: "It is not permissible for a woman to shave her head unless she has an excuse."

Answer (score 1):

If a legal doctor advice you to shave it will be OK

Answer (score 0):

AWW,

Hair shaving is permissable. Ali (ra) often used to have shaved hair. Also, in Hajj and Umrah we shave our hair. And when the Prophet (Saw) saw a child with uneven hair, he said to shave it all or leave it.

حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ حَنْبَلٍ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّزَّاقِ، حَدَّثَنَا مَعْمَرٌ، عَنْ أَيُّوبَ، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ، أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم رَأَى صَبِيًّا قَدْ حُلِقَ بَعْضُ شَعْرِهِ وَتُرِكَ بَعْضُهُ فَنَهَاهُمْ عَنْ ذَلِكَ وَقَالَ ‏ "‏ احْلِقُوهُ كُلَّهُ أَوِ اتْرُكُوهُ كُلَّهُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
 Narrated Abdullah ibn Umar:

The Prophet (ﷺ) saw a boy with part of his head shaved and part left unshaven. He forbade them to do that, saying: Shave it all or leave it all. (Abu Dawood 1563)

Also, a person who is in the state of Ihram is not allowed to cut his hair, but if he has a medical condition, then even in the state of Ihram, he is allowed to cut it, so obviously you can too.

ولا تحلقوا رءوسكم حتى يبلغ الهدي محله فمن كان منكم مريضا أو به أذى من رأسه ففدية من صيام أو صدقة أو نسك 
And do not shave your heads until the sacrificial animal has reached its place of slaughter. And whoever among you is ill or has an ailment of the head [making shaving necessary must offer] a ransom of fasting [three days] or charity or sacrifice (2:196).

Comment: did you notice that the questioner was a **woman**?